# Why are the tags that I just earned not appearing?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, badges, up-votes

I don't really care too much about rep, but I do like the tag upvote answer feature on this site, which I have understood better by looking at the tags of other users.

Here, for example, is the tag upvote answer feature that I am referring to (referencing Andre Nicolas's account):

[image]

So, each of these score's represents the number of upvotes a user has from all of their answers to the tag listed.

So, I recently answered a question that got over 50 upvotes, but the tags never appeared in that feature. I posted an answer just before that one and got 0 votes. However that appeared in my queue.

Well Received Question: [A strange integral having to do with the sophomore's dream:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743348/a-strange-integral-having-to-do-with-the-sophomores-dream/1743351#1743351)

Unvoted question: [Prove that $3^x$ divides $(3x)!\,\,\,\, \forall x \ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741805/prove-that-3x-divides-3x-forall-x-ge-1/1741822#1741822)

Feature: [image]

I am not asking for up votes, but an explanation as to why this phenomenon occurs. My question:

> Is this something common, or is it updated regularly? Will this be fixed?

Comment: If you do not like my use of your profile here without your permission @AndreNicolas, please let me know

Comment: This question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to wait 24 hours and see whether the numbers (scores) will be updated by then. According to an answer posted here (emphasis mine): [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on **answers** under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). As well, posts which are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score. **Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC.**

Although tag-badge may be awarded quicker, not only after the above-mentioned script is run. See: [Do the tag scores now update more often?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272883/do-the-tag-scores-now-update-more-often)

The above information is related to tag-scores, which appear in your profile in the tags tab: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags

The screenshot you provided in your question lists tag badges in the user profile: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile Notice that in order to earn the tag-badge you have to fulfill several criteria (total score in the tag at least 100, at least 20 answers in that particular tag and tag badges can only be earned for the tags which have at least 50 questions). See here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395)

Comment: Hmm, very informative answer. I am fairly new to the site, and so I did not know this. I will wait about a day for this to update, and if not, then I will contact you again.